# In a Groovy class, is getProperty() resolution different when inside method call parenthesis?

Tags: syntax, groovy

This code does not generate an error. (Groovy 2.2.1)

```
public class C {
  def getProperty(String name) {
    name;
  }

  def m(x) {
    println x
    return this;
  }

  def go() {
    r = m x m y m z;  // this is OK
    println r;
  }
}
```

However, this does.

```
public class C {
  def getProperty(String name) {
    Keyword.intern(name);
  }

  def m(x) {
    println x
    return this;
  }

  def go() {
    println(m x m y m z); // this is NOT
  }
}
```

It gives the following error.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
foo.groovy: 39: unexpected
token: x @ line 39, column 19.
       println(m x m y m z); // this is NOT

1 error
```

How do I do this conversion inside method call parens as well as out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, *command chains* (which is the name for this syntactic sugar) are only supported in statement position. At least this was the case when they were introduced in Groovy 1.8.

Comment: Thanks! That's kind of a bummer. Trying to provide consistent and seamless API for others via. groovy and running into things like this make that difficult. At least, it does at my level of experience with Groovy. :)

Comment: You can do: `m x m y m z with { println it }` but that's not very pretty ;-)